# unable to see update from repository in the view but is seen in the vob

Tags: clearcase

I have a view with CCRC.

I want to update the vob from the repository, but it is not showing the option to update it from repository at view level. It is showing it at vob level.
Otherwise, other views are showing options of updating the vob from repository.

Comment: Could you please answer my comments to your previous question?

Answer (score 0):

[Updating an (CCRC web) ClearCase view](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccview_update.htm) is only possible if:

- you are connected to the ClearCase server that supports it, and
- you must create at least one load rule for the view.

So check the config spec associated to the view where this optio is not available.

Comment: we have both the conditions 1. clearcase server is also connected and 2.There is already a vob loaded with that view and the usesrs where working on it since long .